# Is there any way to move the Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin.conf

I'm using a solid state for my boot drive, I'd like to make sure the blockchain goes to my data drive, any way to acomplish this?

Edit: I am using easyminer and bitcoin-qt, it is about moving the blockchain. I looked for something similar. When you don't know what you're looking for it's hard to find answers about it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the hash"? What client software are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about the blockchain, not the hash. Which is the blocks sub-directory of your bitcoin data directory. There are plenty of questions already answered about this.